# mySql insert on joind condition

Tags: mysql

We have two table with this structures:

table_user : id,name

table_user_groups: user_id, group_id

some users has no group so they have no entry in table_user_groups.
I want to determine these users and insert a default `group_id` for them.
I think I have to use an INSERT query with a JOIN condition.
any suggestion.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**UNTESTED**

use this :

```
  INSERT INTO table_user_group
 (SELECT id,'yourdefaultID' FROM table_user WHERE id
 NOT IN (SELECT user_id FROM table_user_groups))
```

Answer (score 0):

The Select statement to get the users you want is that and below that is the cursor for the insert.

```
    SELECT A.id FROM table_user A
    LEFT OUTER JOIN table_user_groups B ON A.id = B.user_id
    WHERE B.user_id = NULL


DECLARE @userid int

DECLARE cursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT A.id FROM table_user A
    LEFT OUTER JOIN table_user_groups B ON A.id = B.user_id
    WHERE B.user_id = NULL

OPEN cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM cursor 
INTO @userid

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    Insert into table_user_groups(user_id,group_id)  VALUES (userid, 'DEFAULTUSERID')
END
CLOSE vendor_cursor;

DEALLOCATE vendor_cursor;
```

Comment: thnks, but where is the insert?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
> INSERT INTO table_user_groups(user_id, group_id)
SELECT tu.id, [DEFAULT ID]
FROM table_user tu
LEFT JOIN table_user_groups tug ON tug.user_id = tu.id
WHERE tug.id IS NULL;
```

Where [DEFAULT ID] is the value what you want to use as default for this users.